# Hibernate shards and JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm evaluating Hibernate Shards for a project that uses hibernate-jpa.

I was wondering how mature is shards when it comes to JPA? The documentation mostly covers the SessionFactory modifications.

Any other recommendations for horizontal partitioning with JPA ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that Hibernate Shards isn't developed very actively and have never gone beyond the first beta. See https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HSHARDS

There is a forked version on https://github.com/karbo/hibernate-shards/tree/hibernate-3.3 which has been upgraded to a newer version of Hibernate.

Spring has some support for this which is outlined here [Multi tenancy in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804738/multi-tenancy-in-hibernate)

Hibernate 4 (JPA) does seem to have multi tenant included: [Spring + Hibernate + JPA + multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703242/spring-hibernate-jpa-multiple-databases)