# Multitenancy with Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, multi-tenant

I am looking around for a multitenancy solution for my web application. 
I would like to implement a application with Separate Schema Model. I am thinking to have a datasource per session. In order to do that i put datasource and entitymanger in session scope , but thats not working. I am thinking to load data-access-context.xml(which include datasource and other repository beans) file when the user entered username and password and tenantId. I would like to know if it is a good solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multitenancy is a bit tricky subject and it has to be handled on the JPA provider side so that from the client code perspective nothing or almost nothing changes. [eclipselink](/questions/tagged/eclipselink) has support for multitenancy (see: [EclipseLink/Development/Indigo/Multi-Tenancy](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/Indigo/Multi-Tenancy)), [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate) just added it recently.

Another approach is to use `AbstractRoutingDataSource`, see: [Multi tenancy in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804738).

Using session-scope is way too risky (also you will end up with thousands of database connections, few for every session/user. Finally `EntityManager` and underlying database connections are not serializable so you cannot migrate your session and scale your app properly.

Comment: Hibernate only supports multitenancy when you use SessionFactory (ie Hibernate native), not JPA (@PersistenceContext/EntityManager) as of yet.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. It really been helpful. And pap you are right. It doesnt support JPA. but I chose to use the  'AbstractRoutingDataSource'. But the problem is now datasource and entitymanager bean initialized at startup. is there anyway to configure this in spring which way that it will initialize after user is authenticated?

Comment: @user1057347: please open a new question, this is a bit too complex to explain in comments (and will not stand out enough in the future). Also please post a link to a new question so I can follow up.

Comment: Here is the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720449/multitenancy-with-spring-security-jpa

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with a number of multi-tenancy systems. The challenge here is how you keep

1. open architecture and
2. provide a solution that evolves with your business.

Let's look at second challenge first. Multi-tenancy systems has a tendency to evolve where you'll need to support use cases where same data (record) can be accessed by multiple tenants with different capacity (e.g. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=355458). So, the system ultimately needs Access Control List.

To keep the open architecture you can code to a standard (like JPA). Coding to EclipseLink or Hibernate makes me uncomfortable.

Spring Security ACL provides very flexible community supported solution to both these challenges. Give that a try. I did and been happy with it's performance. However, I must caution you, it took me some digging to get my head around it.