# Multitenancy with Spring security JPA

Tags: spring-security, multi-tenant

This  is follow up of this [Multitenancy with Spring JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717928/multitenancy-with-spring-jpa)

I chose to use the 'AbstractRoutingDataSource'. But the problem is now datasource and entitymanager bean initialized at startup. is there anyway to configure this in spring which way that it will initialize after user is authenticated?

Another problem which i can think of will be how to handle concurrency. I put tenantId in this class

```java
public class ThreadLocalContextUtil {
 private static final ThreadLocal<String> contextHolder =
            new ThreadLocal<String>();

   public static void setTenantId(String tenantId) {
      Assert.notNull(tenantId, "customerType cannot be null");
      contextHolder.set(tenantId);
   }

   public static String getTenantId() {
      return (String) contextHolder.get();
   }

   public static void clearTenant() {
      contextHolder.remove();
   }
}
```

The solution i can think of will be to remove the tenantId after the datasource is initialized. is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

I've solved similar problem. I implemented my own `TenantAwareDataSource` based on Spring's `AbstractDataSource`. It takes **tenantId** from a session-scoped bean named **tenantContext**. This bean is updated every time the incoming request is processed. It is done by using Spring Security's security filter:

```xml
<security:http auto-config='false' >
    <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="tenantFilter" />
    <!-- ...more security stuff... -->
</security:http>
```

My `TenantAwareDataSource` is initialized in the startup time, but it does not matter because it is created empty - it contains *no tenant datasources* (e.g. pooled JDBC datasources or JPA entity manager). They are created lazily when the `getConnection()` is called for the first time for the selected tenant.

So, my `TenantAwareDataSource` maintains its own dynamic datasource map while `AbstractRoutingDataSource` expects static initializitaion of the datasource map done in the startup time.

Read more detailed description in this [article](http://blog.trixi.cz/2012/01/multitenancy-using-spring-and-postgresql/).

Comment: Hi Actualy i tried your solution. the problem is that "tenantfilter" is session scoped and you get this error java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

Comment: you should Add :   <listener>
            <listener-class>                    org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener 
            </listener-class> 
    </listener> to web.xml