# Two entity managers in Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, entitymanager, transactionmanager

I had done this programmatically at some point - that is creating two entity managers with different data sources and providing them for different services.

However now I am building a webApp using Spring. Thing is that I want to have two entity managers responsible for separate databases. So in my case, half of DAO's would be using **emNumber1**, and second half would be using **emNumber2**. Oh and totally different persistence units as I only need to read data from **DB1** and then process it and store this data in **DB2** in totally different entities.

I am well aware that this problem is and has been going around for sometime now but in different shapes and forms and so I am composing this question only because I could not understand the solutions that were presented withing those googled-up forum threads or they were not applicable to my case. In same cases I could not understand the solution or how to apply it in my case so really sorry for redundant question if it were to be solved by linking a solution from this very own site.

Here is how I find fit to configure a single transaction manager

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
      p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"
      p:username="dbuser"
      p:password="dbuser"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="pu1"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Then inside my dao:

```
public class SimpleDaoImpl implements SimpleDao {
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

    /* methods that use entity manager for transactions and data detcing */
}
```

So in case of two transaction managers with different data sources how would one specify what entity manager to inject into which DAO or is that impossible in Spring?

Comment: did you check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703242/spring-hibernate-jpa-multiple-databases?rq=1

Comment: I found out that if you specify unit name in @PersistenceContext, then spring injects correspcorresponding entity manager... Dont know for sure if this is correct use but it works Fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here i have hibernate with two different data sources and i use @Qualifier to specify the session factory like this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value="sessionFactoryOne")
private SessionFactory sessionFactoryOne;

@Autowired
@Qualifier(value="sessionFactoryTwo")
private SessionFactory sessionFactoryTwo;
```

then i get the session from this guys.

In xml config i have two dataSource, sessionFactory and transactionManager, one for each DB.
Works fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do @PersistenceContext(unitName="pu1")